# Make "no" for WiFi calling permanent

Tags: ios, wifi-calling

Every time we reboot one of our iPads, we are asked to enable WiFi calling.  How do we make it stop asking?  The answer is always No.  We do our calling on our iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to disable this from the iPhone itself.**

Go to Settings →  Cellular → Calls on Other Devices and toggle off the device(s) you don't want to receive calls.

You can disable it entirely (main switch at top) or individually per device.

[image: Calls on Other Devices Toggle Options]

Comment: It was already off on one iPhone.  Interestingly, when I turned it on (temporarily), it said "Unable … must have the devices signed into the same Apple ID."  But all of our devices _are_ signed into the same Apple ID!

Comment: This really looks like the right answer—but, other devices was already off on both phones!  Can it be from a previous phone that has been erased as a trade in?

Comment: Do you have multiple phones with the same AppleID?

Comment: Yes.  Family share doesn't support some of the things we want to share.  So all our devices are on the same Apple ID.

Comment: You have to apply those settings on all phones because, regardless of the phone number, they’ll ring to all devices

Comment: As I said, it _was_ already off on both phones.

Comment: You only have two phones?  I was under the impression there were more

Comment: Two iPhones and 2+ iPads (two working, two broken ages ago and their backups loaded into the two new ones.)

Comment: This has to be disabled on both iPhones. I have tested this exact scenario and disabling it at the iPhone works

Comment: Well, it doesn't work here.  It was _already_ disabled on both phones but the nagging was nevertheless happening.  Further, when I enabled it on one phone, I got that message that it cannot be done because the devices were not on the same Apple ID.  Not only is that false (all the devices _are_ logged in to the same ID), but if it had been true, why were we getting the nagging to accept WiFi calling?

Comment: That doesn’t make sense since only the *phone* can make calling available on other devices.  In other words, your Mac with no cellular capabilities can’t just receive calls because an iPhone happens to be nearby.  Make sure it’s completely off on the phones, reboot the Mac and see if calls still come through

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either.  No calls have come through because I ALWAYS say No to that offer.  And I already saw that it was off when I opened settings on BOTH phones.  Time for a bug report, but why would I have a bug when you don't?  (And now we're being asked to "move to chat" but I'd rather move to bug reporter or to AppleCare)